# Problem with displaying graphs on a Qt canvas

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt

Let's say I'm a Qt newbie.
I want a good Qt library for displaying simple graphs. I've found the quanava library. But there is a problem. When I compiled a basic example it looks like graph edges are not painted properly when moving nodes. I don't have any idea where is a bug but this code seems to be rather simple. I think this is a problem with paint method in NodeItem class. Maybe someone has already solved this problem because this library is quite popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first of all saying graph i mean mathematical concept G=(V,E).
I improved quanava library, which is a very good starting point for graph visualization.

Comment: Please edit this info into your original post rather than making a reply to your post. Then you can delete the reply you made here. In StackOverflow, you're not supposed to make an answer to your own question unless this "answer" describes a solution to your problem or question. Thanks and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

I usually go for [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) for my graphing needs - a bit technical for "office graphs", but still, it works.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Qwt. It gets the job done, and is pretty configurable. The documentation is weak, but the number of examples are extensive enough to make up for it.